# Устранить циклическую зависимость ссылок на классы в Python

Tags: python

Пожалуйста, взгляните на минимизированный код:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class AbstractProduct(ProductFactory, ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def some_method(self):
        ''' Is abstract method '''

class Product1(AbstractProduct):
    def some_method(self):
        print('I am a Product1!')

class Product2(AbstractProduct):
    def some_method(self):
        print('I am a Product2!')

class ProductFactory:
    knowed_types = {
        0: Product1,
        1: Product2
    }

    @classmethod
    def create_product(cls, type_id:int):
        if type_id in cls.knowed_types:
            return cls.knowed_types[type_id]()
```

Этот код не работает, потому что классы упоминают друг друга циклически. Как я могу разорвать циклическую зависимость, не нарушая логику текущего кода? Сниппет предназначен исключительно для демонстрационных целей. Мне не нужно решать проблему конкретно с этим кусочком кода. Я хочу узнать в целом, есть ли в Python встроенный метод устранения подобных циклических зависимостей? Например в Django можно обрамить имя класса в кавычки, чтобы отложить разрешение зависимостей. В C++ можно объявить сигнатуру функции в начале файла, а реализацию - после. Есть ли подобный механизм в чистом Python?

Comment: Кавычки это от самого Питона по-моему, не только в Django я это видел )

Comment: @CrazyElf Нет, это не нативный Python (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881607/django-get-model-from-string)

Comment: не очень понятно почему у вас продукт наследуется от "завода" (`factory`). Несмотря на то, что > "Сниппет предназначен исключительно для демонстрационных целей.", решать абстракную проблему циклических ссылок наследований без контекста - затея дурная. В данном примере лично я вижу только проблему кривой архитектуры.

Comment: @n1tr0xs потому что это минимально воспроизводимый пример. Просто чтобы пользователи понимали что я имею в виду под "циклической зависимостью", а не, например, циклический импорт.

Comment: @n1tr0xs будет ли мой вопрос понятнее, если я удалю код?

Comment: @Aycon он станет понятнее, если вы приведете более приближенный к вашей задаче пример. Чтобы хотя бы общая архитектура классов напоминала вашу. Слишком абстрактный пример скорее вредит вопросу. Вдруг у вас и в вашем реальном проекте проблему архитектуры (хотя я и не утверждаю этого, но такие вопросы уже бывали на SO), а не циклического наследования как такого

Comment: @n1tr0xs нет, это не вопрос архитектуры. Вы предлагаете мне устранить циклическую зависимость, а я спрашиваю, есть ли встроенные средства в Python для этого. Они либо есть, либо их нет. Другой ответ меня не интересует. Не интересует также ответ, который основан на ручном устранении рекурсии. Мне **не нужно** устранять рекурсию, я хочу делать циклические зависимости как в Django. Есть ли такое в Python из коробки или я должен свой велосипед писать?

Comment: На Stackoverflow есть какая-то нездоровая привычка пытаться ответить не на поставленный вопрос, а на додуманный.

Comment: Я хочу, чтобы на такие ответы можно было пожаловаться модератору или проголосовать против.

Comment: @Aycon Ответы можно минусовать. А у комментариев есть флажок, можете его нажать и пожаловаться модератору, если что-то не так по-вашему.

Comment: @Aycon если по-вашему, вам пытаются ответить на "додуманный" вопрос, значит, вы дали для этого повод. недостаточно данных - приходится додумывать. а вот возмущаться желанием других людей разобраться в вашем вопросе, чтобы помочь - это действительно нездоровая привычка.

Comment: @strawdog я представил ответ, который помог бы мне. Он отвечает на вопрос как вообще в Python можно разрешить циклические зависимости. В данном случае - с помощью `type`. Этот ответ не потребовал никакого кода, кроме представленного в вопросе и работает как ожидалось.

Comment: @Aycon потому что вы знаете, что у вас за исходные данные, и чего вы хотите. Для других это _не очевидно_.

Comment: @strawdog как я должен был сформулировать вопрос, чтобы получить приблизительно такой ответ?
Такой, а не предложение переписать архитектуру кода.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

***Помните, что общая статистика голосований не всегда отражает качество ответа: [Голосование за открытие русскоязычного StackOverflow](http://forum.codenet.ru/q73553/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C+%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9+StackOverflow)***

Я решил это, использовав метакласс `type`

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

def custom_inherit(base, *parents, **kwds):
    return type(
        base.__name__,
        (*base.__mro__[1:-1], *parents),
        dict(base.__dict__),
        **kwds
    )

class AbstractProduct:
    @abstractmethod
    def some_method(self):
        ''' Is abstract method '''

class Product1(AbstractProduct):
    def some_method(self):
        ''' Concrete method of Product1 '''
        print('I am a Product1!')

class Product2(AbstractProduct):
    def some_method(self):
        ''' Concrete method of Product2 '''
        print('I am a Product1!')

class ProductFactory:
    knowed_types = {
        0: Product1,
        1: Product2
    }

    @classmethod
    def create_product(cls, type_id:int) -> AbstractProduct:
        if type_id in cls.knowed_types:
            return cls.knowed_types[type_id]()

AbstractProduct = custom_inherit(AbstractProduct, ProductFactory, ABC)

product = AbstractProduct.create_product(1)
product.some_method()
```

Comment: Простое и понятное решение с созданием метода create_product вместо наследования заменили на какой-то ужас...

Comment: Использование плохих средств для обеспечения работы бессмысленных практик.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy пожалуйста, подскажите, что плохого в использовании метакласса `type`? Я постараюсь пересмотреть код этого ответа и исправить его в соответствии с замечаниями.

Answer (score 1):

*tl;dr* Два основных способа:

- изоляция зависимостей внутри тел функций;
- использование строк с названиями объектов вместо самих объектов.

В сегодняшнем вопросе автор почему-то не упомянул нюанс, который он упоминал вчера — он хочет, чтобы метод `create_product` был не только в классе `ProductFactory`, но и в классе `AbstractProduct` («компромисс между удобством использования и удобством поддержки кода»), для чего он и попытался сделать наследование и таким образом получил циклическую зависимость.

Во [вчерашнем (ныне удалённом) вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1545444) я уже предлагал разрешить циклическую зависимость путём замены совершенно нелогичного наследования `AbstractProduct` от `ProductFactory` на простой прокси-метод `create_product` в классе `AbstractProduct`, но автора вопроса это почему-то не устроило и он наотрез отказался объяснять почему.

У людей, слабо знакомых с Python, может возникнуть вопрос — а почему это работает, если даже в моём переделанном коде `ProductFactory` упоминается перед объявлением класса `ProductFactory`? Дело в том, что Python (как и многие другие скриптовые языки) не выполняет проверку корректности кода в телах функций — можно написать в них что угодно, лишь бы синтаксически корректное. Python начнёт искать переменную `ProductFactory` лишь непосредственно в момент вызова функции — а к моменту вызова класс `ProductFactory` уже был создан, поэтому всё работает, а циклическая зависимость успешно побеждена.

Изоляция зависимостей внутри функций и методов — один из способов работы с циклическими зависимостями. Если класс `ProductFactory` находится в другом файле, то можно написать `import` этого класса тоже внутри метода, благо Python позволяет делать импорты в любом месте и в любое время — аналогично, импорт произойдёт только в момент вызова функции.

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class AbstractProduct(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def some_method(self):
        ''' Is abstract method '''

    @staticmethod
    def create_product(type_id:int):
        # Суть — вот в этом методе
        # Если ProductFactory из другого файла, то можно сделать импорт тут:
        # from some_module import ProductFactory
        return ProductFactory.create_product(type_id)

class Product1(AbstractProduct):
    def some_method(self):
        print('I am a Product1!')

class Product2(AbstractProduct):
    def some_method(self):
        print('I am a Product2!')

class ProductFactory:
    knowed_types = {
        0: Product1,
        1: Product2
    }

    @classmethod
    def create_product(cls, type_id:int):
        if type_id in cls.knowed_types:
            return cls.knowed_types[type_id]()

# Теперь можно не использовать ProductFactory напрямую, если так больше нравится
product = AbstractProduct.create_product(1)
product.some_method()
```

---

Для разнообразия также добавлю способ «как в Django» — использование строк с названиями объектов вместо непосредственно этих объектов. Идея в том, чтобы использовать зависимость не сразу, а когда-нибудь потом, найдя её по записанному в строке идентификатору. В примере ниже я изменил `knowed_types` так, чтобы он хранил названия классов, а метод `create_product` ищет эти классы по указанным названиям среди глобальных переменных. В зависимости от ситуации вместо глобальных переменных можно использовать, например, словарь (но тогда нужно будет написать код, который будет заполнять такой словарь — в Django этим занимается метакласс).

(Если объекты находятся в разных файлах, то в той же строке можно прописать путь к модулю, импортировать его с помощью функции [importlib.import_module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) и потом вытащить нужный объект с помощью `getattr`, но в примере ниже это не используется.)

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class ProductFactory:
    knowed_types = {
        # Строки вместо классов!
        0: "Product1",
        1: "Product2"
    }

    @classmethod
    def create_product(cls, type_id:int):
        if type_id in cls.knowed_types:
            # Получаем класс по его имени из какого-то хранилища
            # (в данном примере «хранилищем» служат глобальные переменные)
            product_type_name = cls.knowed_types[type_id]
            product_type = globals()[product_type_name]
            # И создаём экземпляр класса
            return product_type()

# Я осознанно оставил наследование от ProductFactory здесь для примера,
# но имейте в виду, что делать так некрасиво
class AbstractProduct(ProductFactory, ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def some_method(self):
        ''' Is abstract method '''

class Product1(AbstractProduct):
    def some_method(self):
        print('I am a Product1!')

class Product2(AbstractProduct):
    def some_method(self):
        print('I am a Product2!')

product = AbstractProduct.create_product(1)
product.some_method()
```

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149101/discussion-on-answer-by-andreymal------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.